# Android Profiler does not show processes on rooted device

Tags: adb, ram, android-studio

I try to create a memory profile for a specific app using a rooted device:

- The app is not debuggable
- The device is rooted and connected via USB
- USB debugging is enabled
- The device is shown in the android profiler menu
- I use Android Studio 2021.1.1 Patch 1

My problem: My app is not listed in the attachable processes. In fact, the only process listed is, for some reason, Google Maps.
I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-android-studio-memory-profiler/), where it says that "The Android Profiler lists all running processes, even if they aren’t debuggable if you’re using the Android Emulator or a rooted device."

Comment: What device do you use (physical/emulator, model, Android version, ...)?

Comment: Physical device connected via USB, model SM-A526B, Android 12

Comment: Then my guess is that Android 12 makes the difference. That article was written in June 2021 where Android 12 was still in beta, so most likely the article was about Android 11 (or older).